# StackOverflowException in linq query on json object

Tags: c#, json, linq, stack-overflow

I am getting StackOverflowException when I try to run following linq query on following JSON object. It is observed that when the static function enclosing this query executed at the first time it runs well. But the next time it gives the error.

Exception message

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll
```

Here is the query

```
IEnumerable<long> iDs = = from p in jObject["response"]["docs"]
                              select Convert.ToInt64((string)p["id"]);
```

Here is the JSON object

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 4,
    "params": {
      "sort": "noofsales desc, score desc",
      "fl": "id",
      "indent": "false",
      "start": "0",
      "q": "texttags:baby romper  bodysuit jumpsuit unisex boy girl animal costume sizes clothes deal offer\r\ndealtitle:baby romper  bodysuit jumpsuit unisex boy girl animal costume sizes clothes deal offer\r\nwhatyouget:baby romper  bodysuit jumpsuit unisex boy girl animal costume sizes clothes deal offer\r\nalltags:baby romper  bodysuit jumpsuit unisex boy girl animal costume sizes clothes deal offer\r\ndealdescription:baby romper  bodysuit jumpsuit unisex boy girl animal costume sizes clothes deal offer^80\r\ndealcity:National",
      "wt": "json",
      "fq": [
        "dealendtime:[NOW TO NOW+100YEAR]",
        "IF alltags: Experiences THEN dealcity:national National ELSE dealcity:national",
        "soldout:0"
      ],
      "rows": "24"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 35,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "787"
      },
      {
        "id": "23867"
      },
      {
        "id": "920"
      },
      {
        "id": "22768"
      },
      {
        "id": "1018"
      },
      {
        "id": "695"
      },
      {
        "id": "22890"
      },
      {
        "id": "23866"
      },
      {
        "id": "22741"
      },
      {
        "id": "1654"
      },
      {
        "id": "22975"
      },
      {
        "id": "23870"
      },
      {
        "id": "972"
      },
      {
        "id": "974"
      },
      {
        "id": "12379"
      },
      {
        "id": "12201"
      },
      {
        "id": "12199"
      },
      {
        "id": "1261"
      },
      {
        "id": "12205"
      },
      {
        "id": "12198"
      },
      {
        "id": "12191"
      },
      {
        "id": "12209"
      },
      {
        "id": "22919"
      },
      {
        "id": "12203"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: try changing the query to foreach loop and breakdown the conversion states to multiple lines with casting to string and then converting to int and finding expected vs obtained value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ query creates a StackOverflow Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126328/linq-query-creates-a-stackoverflow-exception)